# Is it possible to use the loginPopup() auth flow inside a modal?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, azure-ad-msal

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the MSAL.js loginPopup() method or any other interactive authentication flow inside of a dialog box or modal? I am building an internal application at my job and need to use Azure AD, I have the authentication working but it seems somewhat jarring or out of place from a UX standpoint. I am wanting to be able to style the auth flow container to make it more consistent with the rest of the UI. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Running into it myself